# Is there a way of uploading an image file from a Laravel app to a folder on remote server using an IP?

Tags: php

I have a Laravel app where a user uploads an image. I am able to store it locally but i want to be able to store the image to a folder on another server. I am using PHP file_put_contents() function.

```
$folderPath = public_path('images/');

$image_parts = explode(";base64,", $request->image);
$image_type_aux = explode("image/", $image_parts[0]);
$image_type = $image_type_aux[1];
$image_base64 = base64_decode($image_parts[1]);
$imageName = uniqid() . '.'.$image_type;
$imageFullPath = $folderPath.$imageName;
// saving to the public directory works
// file_put_contents($imageFullPath, $image_base64);
// saving to a remote server
file_put_contents('REMOTE SERVER IP/Pictures/', $image_base64);
```

I get this error
message:"file_put_contents(REMOTE SERVER IP/Pictures/): failed to open stream: No such file or directory"

Comment: Yeah, you can't do that. You'll have to use something like ssh2_sftp(), or mount the remote directory to the local server (with NFS or CIFS or whatever) and then use the local server's path in your file_put_contents() call. Or build an upload API on that other server.